# Is 'err' a reserved word for an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning the MEAN stack and when I'm setting up my mongoDB with mongoose I use this:

```
mongoose.connect(mongooseUrl, function(err){
if(err){
    console.log('There\'s been an error');
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log('Connected to '+ mongooseUrl + '!');
}
```

I just wanted to know if 'err' is a reserved keyword for error in JS.

Thank you!

Comment: Reserved words are in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words), though annoyingly they're not listed alphabetically. "err" is not one of them.

Comment: @RobG why does it return 'the' error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not... it is a completely arbitrary name that you assign yourself to a first function parameter in the arguments list

Comment: this is a standard convention for async callbacks used by node.js of first-error argument functions as callbacks (which is in itself adopted from [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)). You can read more about it here -> http://callbackhell.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'm having a hard time with the callback functions.

Comment: you are welcome... I recon that callbackhell article will help you alot